# Defining Resource ID's in an array in a header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to define a contiguous range of RID's in a vector format in the header file:

```
    #include<vector>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<iostream>

    #define vector<int> IDM_POPUP_LAST (5);
    for(i = 0; i < IDM_POPUP_LAST.size(); i++)
    IDM_POPUP_LAST [i] = i + 90;
```

Is there anything missing here. I have a set of errors:

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. You need to move those bottom 3 to whatever function you're using them in.

Comment: I m trying to pass a RID to a function so that can be handled there. so how can I move the other RID's in the function in which it is being used.Should I define the RID of  IDM_POPUP_LAST in header file?

Comment: When you use 'define',  'IDM_POPUP_LAST' is only a type, and you couldn't use it as a variable.

Comment: what's all the shouting about?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to have a statically initialized data and you want it to be in a `vector`'s object (if I understand you correctly). Unfortunately this is not possible to do in C++ in this way. However there are other options you could explore:

1) Use a static array, something like this:

```
int IDM_POPUP_LAST[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

2) Have a vector that is initialized either early in `main()` or by a dummy class's constructor, like this:

```
vector<int> IDM_POPUP_LAST(5);
struct DummyInitializer
{
  DummyInitializer()
  {
    // code to initialize the vector IDM_POPUP_LAST
  }
} global_var_so_the_constructor_is_called_before_main;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declaration is wrong. Variables are normally declared with the syntax:

```
std::vector<int> IDM_POPUP_LAST (5);
```

Besides that, the `for` can't simply be put outside of a function.

That being said, this is probably something you'd use as a global variable. One way to get around that is to make it a static member of a class, with a function to initialize it. You can even add other types of ids in here when you decide you want them, and add initializing them to the function as needed:

```
//resource.h

struct ResourceIDs {
    static std::vector<int> menus;
    static void init();

    //Let's add in three cursors
    static std::vector<int> cursors;
};

//NOTE - these are all better off in a .cpp
#include "resources.h" //if in the cpp

std::vector<int> ResourceIDs::menus (5); //define the menus member
std::vector<int> ResourceIDs::cursors (3); //define the cursors member

void ResourceIDs::init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < menus.size(); ++i) //note the type mismatch since vector
        menus[i] = i + 90;                 //uses size_t, which is unsigned

    //let's do cursors starting at 150
    for (int i = 0; i < cursors.size(); ++i)
        cursors[i] = i + 150;
}
```

Now you just need to make sure to initialize them, and then you can use them wherever you need:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

int main() {
    ResourceIDs::init();
    //create window, message loop, yada yada
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        //check the menu ids using ResourceIDs::menus[x]

        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

The only difference here from what code #define-ing the ids should look like is a call to `ResourceIDs::init()` at the start of `main`, the need for `ResourceIDs::`, and the array syntax.